# PHP PDO potential logical error

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I'm new to PHP and would like to know why this code doesn't insert anything to the DB (returns 0). I'm sure it has to be a logical error, as I'm not getting any error messages.

```
class DbConnection {
    protected $db_conn;
    public $db_host = "localhost";
    public $db_name = "todo";
    public $db_user = "root";
    public $db_pass = "";

    function connect () {
        try {
            $this->db_conn = new PDO ("mysql: host = $this->db_host; dbname = $this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage ();
        }
    }
}

class ManageUsers {
    public $link;

    function __construct () {
        $db_connecton = new DbConnection ();
        $this->link = $db_connecton->connect ();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers ($username, $password, $ip_address, $reg_time, $reg_date) {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, ip_address, reg_time, reg_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array ($username, $password, $ip_address, $reg_time, $reg_date);
        $query->execute ($values);
        $counts = $query->rowCount ();
        return $counts;
    }

}

$users = new ManageUsers ();
echo $users->registerUsers ("bob", "lassie", "127.0.0.2", "13:37", "03-14-15");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't put spaces in your `PDO` connection otherwise it will assume strange things e.g. it thinks that you db name is: `[space]todo` and so on, so just remove every space in your connection string, like this:

```
$this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
                             //^     ^              ^      ^no spaces
```

Comment: I'd call this one, an "assist". Good job  Riz ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, I know I have a habit of putting spaces everywhere, which makes the code more pretty imo, but this practice hasn't backfired yet.

Comment: @Martin It's always good to get another pair of eyes to look at it ;-) cheers